# necessity of prototype declaration in every method

Tags: javascript

Is is necessary to have "prototype" appended to every method of class.. or namespace is enough in example below (for full example refer link below). I understand that it is good practice but do inheritance really require the keyword "prototype" declare in every method.. what is the real necessity inheritance

```
if(animal === undefined) var animal  = {};

animal.Mammal.prototype.haveABaby=function(){ 
    var newBaby=new Mammal("Baby "+this.name);
    this.offspring.push(newBaby);
    return newBaby;
} 
animal.Mammal.prototype.toString=function(){ 
    return '[Mammal "'+this.name+'"]';
}
```

http://phrogz.net/JS/classes/OOPinJS2.html

Comment: If you try asking this without using the words "method," "class," or "namespace," you'll probably end up answering your own question.

Answer (score 2):

prototype has nothing to see with namespace.

You define a function on prototype so that all objects created with `new Mammal()` will have this function (method) :

```
Mammal.prototype.haveABaby=function(){
...

var phoque = new Mammal();
var d = phoque.haveABaby();
```

In this case, all instances will share the same function. If you'd had defined the function on your instance, you'd have used more memory (not necessarily significant), and instance creation would have been longer.

If you want, you may combine it with namespaces :

```
animal = animal || {}; // note the simplification
animal.Mammal.prototype.haveABaby=function(){ 
...
var phoque = new animal.Mammal();
var d = phoque.haveABaby();
```

But those are two different topics.

[Here's a good description of the link between prototype and inheritance.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

Answer (score 1):

it's needed.

If you don't have *prototype* then the function only gets added to the current instance.  Using *prototype* means that when you user the *new* keyword, the new object will also get a copy of the function.

ie:

```
Mammal.toString = function() {...};
```

would put the *toString* function on *Mammal* - but would *NOT* put a *toString* function on every instance of *Mammal*.  e.g. using the above non-prototype declaration:

```
var aDog = new Mammal();
aDog.toString()  //result in undefined
```

Comment: thx for excellent explaination.. but if we have 2 different type of shapes circle & rectanlge both extending to function say shape.. depending on value of pass say 'c' or 'r' the shape function "area" method is called will it still require the prototype keyword associated to every method or without it still conceptually it is correct.. please refer the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/brijeshdkac/sqwfu/ ... fiddle is just not exact but psuedo code..

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/2DvQ5/1/ for a clearer answer (I hope).  you would normally define common functions (that are shared between multiple different shapes) on the shape class, so that you only have to write them once.